# a sub viewcontroller notify the root viewcontroller to load another sub viewcontroller

Tags: iphone

I have a project in which the root viewcontroller call multi viewcontrollers. There is button on a sub viewcontroller's view, when I press the button, I hope it notify the root view controller to load another sub viewcontroller.

```
//the function in this viewcontroller

-(IBAction)submitButtonPressed:(id)sender;
{
     [self.parentViewController   notifyLoadAnotherViewContrller ] ; 

}   


//the function in root viewcontroller
-(void) notifyLoadAnotherViewContrller 
{

    Submit *tController = [[AnotherViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"AnotherViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.vanotherViewController = tController;

    [tController release];


    [self.view insertSubview:tController.view atIndex:10];



}
```

but this does not works
I set the breakpoint in function -(void) notifyLoadAnotherViewContrller

it does not work I checked the function name, no problem.

What is reason I am doing wrong?

Welcome any comment

Best Regards

interdev

Comment: can u cahnge [tController release]; to [tController autorelease]; and see what happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So some standard debugging...  Set a breakpoint in submitButtonPressed: to make sure your IBAction is properly connected.  Examine parentViewController to make sure it's what you expect.

Since the method is not getting called, then your button is either not connected in Interface Builder or your parentViewController is nil, which will silently ignore the method call.